# Is there any ways to simplify the process of creating subsites

Tags: site-template, sub-site

I have create a parent site for a department that has many sub sites for its  projects. The manager of the department wants to create sub-sites whenever the new project come. Is there any way to simplify the process of creating sub-sites. So he just have to click once or twice max on parent site and the sub-site be created.

Note: I have template stored in solution gallery to create for the sub-sites.

Many thanks

Comment: What's your SharePoint Version ? also, if you add link at the main site to create a subsite is enough for you ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am using SharePoint 2016. I think my manager wants bit more simple and it would be great if there is any way. On the site creation form, can we reduce the number of fields to enter. Therefore, he just enter the name, description and URL name. Template selection option should be one rather than all the options with all tabs. and it use by default same permission as parent site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add link in left navigation. it will be very simple and easy to create subsite. Just try it out.

Go to Site Settings ---> Navigation ---> Add link in left navigation

Give title : "Create Subsite"

Give Url : https://YourSiteUrl/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx

Comment: Thanks Vishal, it really solves my 50% problem. is there any way to reduce the number of fields to enter during site creation. Just have to enter the name, description and URL name. Template selection option should be one rather than all the options with all tabs. and it can use by default 'same permission as parent site'.

Comment: For that you have create webpart with text boxes for name, description, url name and one button that creates subsite using entered data & your custom site template. finally add this webpart on one page and give link in left navigation.